# Show multiple values in one textbox

Tags: docusignapi

Can I show a combination of two values in one single Textbox which are been sent via API as separate tabs? Can Data Label have something like FirstName+LastName ?
I.E:
I'm sending first name and last name as two tabs:

```
new Text()
{
   TabLabel = "FirstName",
   Value = model.FirstName
},
new Text()
{
   TabLabel = "LastName",
   Value = model.LastName
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifying two separate text tabs (as you show in the code you posted), the value of each tab will be displayed in its own text box in the DocuSign signing UI.

If you want both first name and last name to appear within the same text box in the UI, you'd need to concatenate those those values to specify the value of a *single* tab.

```
new Text()
{
   TabLabel = "Name",
   Value = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Data Label can have something like FirstName+LastName. But when you need to populate value in the dataLabel, it needs to come from your code. You need to concatenate values from your data model to this data label.

```
new Text()
{
   TabLabel = "FirstName+LastName",
   Value = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName
}
```